# JPA native query gives incorrect output

Tags: sql, hibernate, postgresql

I know this may sound silly but I've been stuck on this problem for too long!

I'm querying a PostgreSQL repository through JPA using native SQL queries. One of my queries looks like this:

```
@Query(value = "select * from gs where ?1 = ?2", nativeQuery = true)
public List<GsJsonStore> matchJson(String term, String value);
```

I'm testing the function using :

```
List<GsJsonStore> list = repo.matchJson("subject", "'Sub'");
```

The list is empty on running the query, however when I run the same query through PSQL command line using:

```
select * from gs where subject = 'Sub';
```

I get the correct output, records contatining the key-value pair are returned.

Where am I making the mistake?

Comment: when you debug, what query string do you get?

Comment: They are not the same query. Your native query in JPA translates to `... where 'subject' = '''Sub'''` (which will always give empty results). Native queries still uses prepared statements, you cannot use them for building the query (they can only be used for binding parameter values).

Comment: This is the hibernate trace:
select * from gs where ? = ?
binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - ['Sub']
binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [subject]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use parameter for column name. Your query resolves to

```
select * from gs where 'subject' = '''Sub'''
```

EDIT: just saw @pozs already posted the same in comment